# Infinite Type error while attempting exercise in Binary Tree example

Tags: elm

In working through Exercise 2 [here](http://elm-lang.org/examples/binary-tree), I offered this solution to the compiler and got an Infinite Type error.

```
flatten : Tree a -> List a
flatten tree =
  case tree of
    Empty -> []
    Node v left right ->
      [v] :: flatten left :: flatten right
```

This doesn't seem too different from my solution to the first exercise:

```
sum : Tree Int -> Int
sum tree =
  case tree of
    Empty -> 0
    Node v left right ->
        v + sum left + sum right
```

I wondered if perhaps the issue had to do with order of operations, so I added parens to ensure `flatten` gets evaluated before `::`, but this doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
flatten : Tree a -> List a
flatten tree =
  case tree of
    Empty -> []
    Node v left right ->
      [v] :: (flatten left) :: (flatten right)
```

So now I'm just stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::` is the [`cons` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons), which means it will prepend a single element onto a list. Its type signature is `a -> List a -> List a`. That means this isn't valid code since the first argument, `[v]` is a list:

```elm
[v] :: flatten left :: flatten right -- invalid!
```

If you want to concatenate two lists, you use the concatenation operator: `++`. You could just replace `::` with `++` in your example to get it to compile:

```elm
[v] ++ flatten left ++ flatten right
```

Another way to represent that line is to concatenate the two lists, then prepend the list with `v` using the `cons` operator.

```elm
v :: flatten left ++ flatten right

-- The following is the same as above, but with parentheses showing precedence
v :: (flatten left ++ flatten right)
```

There are more efficient ways to do this, of course, but it highlights the difference between `cons` and concatenation.

The reason your `sum` example works is because it is returning an int instead of a list of ints. The type you are returning in `sum` is the same as the value in the tree, so you end up with an aggregate, not another list.

Comment: Doh! So obvious in hindsight. Thanks! For bonus points (feel free to ignore), what's an example of one of the "more efficient ways" that you hinted at?

Comment: Hint: try writing `flatten` without using concatenation. Concatenating linked lists is always more expensive than building lists using `cons` alone.